# How seriously do string theorists take the "landscape"

Tags: string-theory, string-theory-landscape

The string theory landscape seems to this outside observer to be  an intermediate step in the intellectual progress toward a more robust theory that explains why our one universe has the particular properties that it has. is this the majority opinion or do most string theorists view the landscape as a plausibly being included in the final form of the theory?

Comment: This is going to depend on the string theorist. There is no "official" string theory answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about other people, but the notion that there is a unique 4d solution for our universe I find a little preposterous--- the situation is exactly the same as for Newtonian mechanics and the solar system--- the solar system has many different possible configurations, you can't predict that Jupiter will be this and such size at this and such a distance, but you can predict general features, and find the general laws.

It is not possible that string theory will be shown to uniquely predict our universe, since it allows for 11 dimensional stable vacuum, along with 10 dimensional ones, and so on. So the landscape isn't going away. In point of fact, the landscape was already appreciated by Scherk and Schwarz in the 1970s, when they did toroidal compactifications, but it was politically inconvenient, since it suggested that it will be difficult to predict experimental results from string theory. Because of this, some people kept on saying that the theory has a unique vacuum well into the 1990s, although this was already clear in 1977.

Comment: This is clearly right. But "landscape" also gets used, perhaps sloppily, as a shorthand for the picture of eternal inflation populating all of these vacua. And I think that's, rightly, a lot more controversial.

Comment: @MattReece: Eternal inflation is not only controversial, I consider it dead, since it is holographically ridiculous. I think this is now commonly said by all the usual suspects in the holographic mafia (Fischler/Susskind/Banks/Shenker).

Comment: But why should we believe in holography rather than eternal inflation? There's no actual experimental evidence for either one.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Given that Susskind and Shenker have written papers trying to build a holographic theory of eternal inflation (by taking the perspective of a late-time FRW observer), I don't think they agree that it's dead. E.g. Sekino/Susskind in http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3844: "In this paper a holographic description of eternal inflation is developed." So I think "controversial" is the status, even among people who take holography seriously....

Comment: @RonMaimon If a string theory wont ever be able to predict it, how do you account for our vacua without resorting to the anthropic principle (which is pretty obviously giving up)? I'm curious what your thoughts on this are Ron because I respect your opinion. Will we have to look for a yet deeper theory to explain their values? ;)

Comment: @PeterShor: Because eternal inflation has a measure paradox, which arises whenever you try to make sense of the exterior of the cosmological horizon, while holography is consistent. Experimental evidence has not been a clue we can use for these things since 1916, we just have to polish up the politics so that we can make progress in the absence of direct evidence, and this is possible as physics has shown, but extremely difficult, because you need honesty whips.

Comment: @MattReece: This is Susskind being political. The holographic version of EI is not EI, it is one-patch EI, which is nothing like the picture EI gives. Nobody who takes holography seriously can take inflation seriously, it was obvious already in 1994 that EI is wrong.

Comment: @James: I think that dS space is described by a thermal ensemble within string theory, since this is the only way I see to make sense of the finite area horizon. The idea is that there is only a finite amount of information available, and the rest is thermally random, so the cosmological horizon is finite area. There is no precise picture of this. The thermal ensemble of inflation is a probability distribution on vacua, and anthropic isn't bad, there aren't that many vacua--- $10^{500}$ is a small number, arbitrariness is measured in log, there are more possible solar systems.

Comment: @RonMaimon So if you accept M theory you have to accept multiverses ? There's no possibility of a theory developing within the framework that doesn't need multiverses? To phrase it snippily,  I dont think we should blame the laws of our universe for the theory's lack of precision. Unlike Woit and co I dont think we should abandon string theory it obviously looks correct but don't you think it's too early to give up.  Theres still lots we dont know right? There's a possibility it can be made more precise, no?

Comment: @James: I never said multiverse, I said probability, the two are not quite the same--- you need probability for things like predicting the mass of Jupiter, and the number of stars in the Milky way, and why not for our detailed vacuum. That's not the eternal inflation multiverse, which is both ill conceived in light of holography and gives inconsistent probabilities.

Comment: @Ron: there's always the possibility that we don't understand probability in the light of the eternal inflation multiverse yet, and that it rather than holography is the right answer. If we threw out all physics theories that seemed to be inconsistent, then we would never have discovered quantum mechanics or relativity.

Comment: @PeterShor: Except it looks like we _do_ understand it, it's not mathematically inconsistent as an idea, it's just obviously totally wrong in that it wants to maximize inflation time. The idea is preposterous in light of holography, there is no doubt which is right, and holography doesn't allow real EI.

Answer (score 2):

That there are multiple possible solutions isn't seriously questioned, but I note this recent paper [The Top $10^{500}$ Reasons Not to Believe in the Landscape](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5715). This is not questioning the existance of $10^{500}$ solutions, but it is questioning the interpretation as a landscape. Specifically the paper claims the solutions are entirely separate and you cannot have transitions between solutions within it.

Comment: This is Bank's old schtick, and it gets annoying--- what he is saying is that different Hamitlonians means different theories. But one just _knows_ that Matrix theory and AdS/CFT are linked by compactification and adding branes, and these cannot be disconnected, although they are in Banks' technical sense of not being able to move from one to the other with a finite number of excitations. The points he make about EI being incompatible with holography are well taken (and clear), although you don't need Bousso, there is no failure in computing fluctuations in local coordinates.

Comment: It's impossible for us outsiders to judge the merit of papers like this, though I note it hasn't made it to a refereed journal (yet). Sean Carroll appears to be taking it seriously (http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/).

Comment: Forget about refereeing, it is useless for radical stuff like this. Of course one has to take what Banks says seriously--- he understands holography.